# Trello REST API: Delete Custom Field item from a Card

Tags: api, rest, trello

How do I delete a Custom Field item from a card, using Trello REST API?

The documentation only mentions [updating](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/#api-cards-idCard-customField-idCustomField-item-put), not removing an already set value.
The closest I'll get, is setting an empty value, like this:

```
{
  "value": {
    "text": ""
  }
}
```

When I'll then fetch the card in JSON format (card url + `.json` at the end), it's still shows up among other `customFieldItems`, with an empty value.
If I manually clear the value using Trello in the browser, the custom field item is removed from the card, and no longer shows up in the json format.

How can I achieve the same thing, but using the REST API ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/getting-started-with-custom-fields#clearing-customfielditems), this can be done by setting an empty string for value.

i.e. instead of

```
{
  "value": {
    "text": ""
  }
}
```

you want to send a request with

```
{
  "value": ""
}
```

It took me a while to figure this out because the documentation is kind of confusing and has empty strings for everything else as well, but this one particular empty string is useful.